# How to remove the indentation from the address field in amsart

Tags: indentation, amsart

I don't know if this behavior is common to other document classes, but the address line at the end of the pdf in amsart begins with a kind of indentation.

Here there is a MWE that should highlight what I mean by the foregoing:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\address{University of Nowhere-Upon-Lostland \\ Department of Metamatics \\ Rue Unknown 0 \\ Neverland N-0000}

\title{Hello world}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove that indentation so that the address is aligned on the left as everything else?

I already tried with

```
\address{\noindent \noindent University of Nowhere-Upon-Lostland \\ Department of Metamatics \\ Rue Unknown 0 \\ Neverland N-0000}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class uses `\@setaddresses` to typeset the address information, which contains four instances of `\indent` and you want to turn them into `\noindent`.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\indent}{\noindent}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\address{University of Nowhere-Upon-Lostland \\ 
  Department of Metamatics \\ Rue Unknown 0 \\ Neverland N-0000}
\curraddr{Somewhere}
\email{xyz@abc.def}
\urladdr{https://example.com}

\title{Hello world}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]